# BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization проблемы синхронизацией

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется `ObservableCollection` привязанная к `PageCollectionView`* созданный на основе `ListCollectionView`.

```
 public VM()
 {
      _customs = new ObservableCollection<CustomVM>();
      PageCollectionView = new PageCollectionView(_customs, 100);
 }
```

*класс делит внутренний список на страницы. логики затрагивающее асинхронное чтение/запись и т.д. не добавлено.

Коллекция заполнялась в фоновом потоке при помощи:

```
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { /*добавление элемента в коллекцию */ });
```

Все работает отлично, пока коллекция не начинает активно заполнятся, в следствие чего UI - поток блокируется до тех пор пока коллекция не перестанет заполнятся.

Выходом из ситуации было использовать `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` и добавлять элементы без `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`:

```
 private object lockObj = new object(); 

 public VM()
 {
      _customs = new ObservableCollection<CustomVM>();
      BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_customs, lockObj);
      PageCollectionView = new PageCollectionView(_customs, 100);
 }
```

UI - поток перестал блокироваться при активном заполнении коллекции, НО я заметил что `ListCollectionView.InternalList` возвращает каждый раз **разное** количество элементов, в следствие чего не правильно рассчитываются некоторые свойства в `PageCollectionView`.

Нашел похожую [проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233215/6936696), но решение там свелось к использованию как `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.

Как с этим бороться, чтобы ListCollectionView.InternalList при обращении возвращало все элементы?.

Comment: А как выглядит `/*добавление элемента в коллекцию */`? Там есть что-то кроме собственно добавления?

Comment: @VladD, нет, обычный _customs.Add(new CustomVM());

Comment: Ещё вопрос: а может, вы при заполнении коллекции с `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` где-то забыли `lock (lockObj)`?

Comment: А создание `CustomVM` быстрое?

Comment: @VladD, кстати я пробовал как с lock(lockObj) при добавлении так и без. разницы не заметил. CustomVM быстрое, там просто обертка над моделью в пару свойств.

Comment: `lock` необходим для случая с `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`, иначе возможен race condition (который производит эффект «редко, но метко»).

Comment: Ещё: документация пишет, что в случае с `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` WPF держит у себя копию вашей коллекции, которую обновляет в фоне (так что размер в WPF вовсе не обязательно всегда в точности соответствует размеру коллекции, например). Но это ж для вас не критично?

Comment: @VladD, хм, наверное не критично если я привязываюсь не к копии? кстати я попробовал заменить ListCollectionView на CollectionView добавив свое свойство IList InternalList и на удивление размер коллекции возвращается правильный, но при таком подходе перестает работать фильтрация

Comment: Ну, может, вы берёте индекс элемента из WPF-копии коллекции, и пытаетесь по нему получить доступ к оригинальной коллекции, мало ли. А эти коллекции могут временно быть разной длины. Я на всякий случай переспросил.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123576/discussion-between-gardes-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1):

Прочитав документацию [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=net-5.0) можно заметить что:

> CollectionView поддерживает «теневую копию» коллекции для использования в потоке пользовательского интерфейса.

> В итоге вы можете изменить коллекцию в любом потоке, и эти изменения в конечном итоге появятся в ItemsControl, когда поток пользовательского интерфейса успеет «наверстать упущенное». Реализация была настроена таким образом, чтобы регулировать скорость изменения потока в потоке пользовательского интерфейса, чтобы фоновые потоки не перегружали поток пользовательского интерфейса и не позволяли реагировать на обычный пользовательский ввод.

и сделать вывод: что InternalList это и есть та самая "теневая копия" которая отстает от оригинальной коллекции, чтобы не тормозить UI.